# out of ambition, not out of a belief

Tags: meaning

> Evans also records that Müller was a regime functionary out of ambition, not out of a belief in National Socialism. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_M%C3%BCller_%28Gestapo%29))

I would like to know the precise meaning of the phrase "out of ambition and out of belief" in the sentence above. From the context of the article I came to the opinion that HM was not a truthful believer in Nazi ideology, that he was the sort of an opportunist. But the phrase "out of ambition, not out of a belief in National Socialism" asserts something totally different, at least when translating it literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis of the excerpt is correct: Evans notes that Muller came to be an official in the Nazi regime not because he believed in National Socialism, but rather because of his personal ambition (opportunism).

(By translating it literally, do you mean translating with Google translate? Because in that case it can confuse you by translating "out of" to mean "no longer in possession of", instead of its intended meaning here: Because of, or due to.)

Comment: Right - emphasis here is that  _"was a functionary out of ambition, not out of belief"_ means the same thing as _"was not a truthful believer in Nazi ideology, that he was the sort of an opportunist"_  The phrase "out of" can be translated in more than one way.  A "fish out of water" is very different from "a thief out of desperation."  In this quote, "out of" matches the latter use.